# Java game - problem with collision between 2 characters

Tags: java, collision-detection, game-physics

I'm implementing a 2d game in java based on tiles and I have a problem with collision between the hero (the rabbit) and the enemy(the snake).

I want to implement the collision such that when the snake touch the rabbit then the rabbit dies. So for this I created a Rectangle on the snake and other on Rabbit and then I used the intersect method. In my code I write a message "Collided" when snake touch the rabbit but when I start the game the message "Collided" appears even these 2 characters don't collide. It;s like one of those 2 rectangle has the dimensions of the map.

The snake class and Player class extends the Creature class which extends the Entity class.

The Snake class

```
package BunnyFights.Entities.Creatures;

import BunnyFights.Handler;
import BunnyFights.States.GameState;
import BunnyFights.Tiles.Tile;
import BunnyFights.gfx.Assets;

import javax.sql.rowset.spi.XmlReader;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Snake extends Creature {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private boolean isDead, heroDead;

    public Snake(Handler handler, float x, float y) {
        super(handler, x, y, DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH, DEFAULT_CREATURE_HEIGHT);

        bounds.x = 16;
        bounds.y = 32;
        bounds.width = 32;
        bounds.height = 32;

    }

    @Override
    public void tick() {
        if(isDead)
            return;
       move();
        //update collision bounds location
      // bounds.x = (int) x;
      // bounds.y = (int) y;

    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        if(isDead)
            return;
        // Render the snake
        g.drawImage(image, (int)(x - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()), (int)(y - handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()), width, height, null);
        // The snake Rectancle
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect((int)(x + bounds.x - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()),
                (int)(y + bounds.y - handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()),
                bounds.width, bounds.height);
    }

    public void die(){
        isDead = true;}

    public void moveToPlayer(Player player) {
        float deltaX = player.getX() - this.getX();
        float deltaY = player.getY() - this.getY();
        float hyp = (float) Math.sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY);

        deltaX /= hyp;
        deltaY /= hyp;

        this.setxMove(deltaX * speed);
        this.setyMove(deltaY * speed);
    }

    public void rotateSnake(Player player) {

        if (((player.getX() < (this.getX()+50)) && (player.getX() > (this.getX()-50))) && player.getY() > this.getY()) {
            image = Assets.snakeFace;
        }
        else if (player.getX() > (this.getX()+50)) {
            image = Assets.snakeRight;
        }
        else {
            image = Assets.snakeLeft;
        }

        if (((player.getX() < (this.getX()+50)) && (player.getX() > (this.getX()-50))) && player.getY() < this.getY()) {
            image = Assets.snakeBack;
        }
    }

    public void snakePlayerRelation(Player player) {
        tick();
        moveToPlayer(player);
        rotateSnake(player);
    }


    public boolean getDead() {
        return isDead;
    }



    @Override
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }




}
```

The Player class

```
package BunnyFights.Entities.Creatures;

import BunnyFights.Handler;
import BunnyFights.States.GameState;
import BunnyFights.Tiles.Tile;
import BunnyFights.gfx.Assets;

import javax.sql.rowset.spi.XmlReader;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Snake extends Creature {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private boolean isDead, heroDead;

    public Snake(Handler handler, float x, float y) {
        super(handler, x, y, DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH, DEFAULT_CREATURE_HEIGHT);

        bounds.x = 16;
        bounds.y = 32;
        bounds.width = 32;
        bounds.height = 32;

    }

    @Override
    public void tick() {
        if(isDead)
            return;
       move();
        //update collision bounds location
      // bounds.x = (int) x;
      // bounds.y = (int) y;

    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        if(isDead)
            return;
        // Render the snake
        g.drawImage(image, (int)(x - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()), (int)(y - handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()), width, height, null);
        // The snake Rectancle
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect((int)(x + bounds.x - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()),
                (int)(y + bounds.y - handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()),
                bounds.width, bounds.height);
    }

    public void die(){
        isDead = true;}

    public void moveToPlayer(Player player) {
        float deltaX = player.getX() - this.getX();
        float deltaY = player.getY() - this.getY();
        float hyp = (float) Math.sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY);

        deltaX /= hyp;
        deltaY /= hyp;

        this.setxMove(deltaX * speed);
        this.setyMove(deltaY * speed);
    }

    public void rotateSnake(Player player) {

        if (((player.getX() < (this.getX()+50)) && (player.getX() > (this.getX()-50))) && player.getY() > this.getY()) {
            image = Assets.snakeFace;
        }
        else if (player.getX() > (this.getX()+50)) {
            image = Assets.snakeRight;
        }
        else {
            image = Assets.snakeLeft;
        }

        if (((player.getX() < (this.getX()+50)) && (player.getX() > (this.getX()-50))) && player.getY() < this.getY()) {
            image = Assets.snakeBack;
        }
    }

    public void snakePlayerRelation(Player player) {
        tick();
        moveToPlayer(player);
        rotateSnake(player);
    }


    public boolean getDead() {
        return isDead;
    }



    @Override
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }




}
```

The GameState class where I call the methods.

```
package BunnyFights.States;

import BunnyFights.Entities.Creatures.*;
import BunnyFights.Game;
import BunnyFights.Handler;
import BunnyFights.Tiles.Tile;
import BunnyFights.Worlds.World;
import BunnyFights.gfx.Assets;

import java.awt.*;

public class GameState extends State {

    private Player player;
    private World world;
    private Snake snake1;
    private Gun gun;

    private int snake1Life = 4;

    public GameState(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
        world = new World(handler,"res/worlds/world.txt");
        handler.setWorld(world);
        player = new Player(handler,300,300);
        snake1 = new Snake(handler, 100, 100);
        snake1.setSpeed(3.1f);
        snake1.snakePlayerRelation(player);    
        gun = new Gun(handler,player.getX(),player.getY());



    }

    @Override
    public void tick() {
        //fire gun if mouse clicked
        if(handler.getMouseManager().isLeftPressed()){
            gun.fire(player.getX(),player.getY(),handler.getMouseManager().getMouseX(),handler.getMouseManager().getMouseY());
        }

        world.tick();
        player.tick();
        snake1.snakePlayerRelation(player);
        gun.tick();

        //reduce snake life, if it gets hit by bullet
        for(Bullet b : gun.getBullets()){
            if(b.getBounds().intersects(snake1.getBounds())){
                System.out.println("Bullet collided with snake1");
                b.die();
                snake1Life--;
            }
        }

        //snake dies if it lives reaches 0
        if(snake1Life <= 0){
            snake1.die();
        }
        
        // here I implemented the detection using intersect method.
        if (player.getBounds().intersects(snake1.getBounds())) {
            System.out.println("Collided");
            //player.die();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        world.render(g);
        player.render(g);
        snake1.render(g);
        gun.render(g);
    }


}
```

Another thing weird is that if you look in the snake and player class in the tick method I have 2 commented instruction which should update the rectangle coordinates. If I remove those comments the collision is working but the rectangle are not anymore on my players, the rectangles are moving faster than the players.

Here's a video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTJ1O9t-jP4

The snake rectangle is also black, that s the reason you don;t see it, the background is green but the recorder made it black.

Comment: I think you forgot to post your Player class

Comment: Output the values from your bounds method that's used for the intersection and verify the data is correct.  I don't see where the player/snake moves ever updates the bounds x and y values, is that inside the creature class?